# Datetime module and Pandas to_datetime give different results

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc, localtime

I have a string containing a UTC datetime

```
utc_str = '2017-11-21T23:00+0100'
```

which in my local time (Europe/Berlin) is:

```
local_time = '2017-11-22 00:00'
```

And is the desired value I would like to obtain from `utc_string`.

I can convert `utc_string` to `local_time` just fine using:

```
import datetime as dt
utc_time = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z')
local_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))

print(local_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
>>> 2017-11-22 00:00
```

However, when I use `Pandas`, I get a different result.  It doesn't seem to apply the UTC offset:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_date = pd.to_datetime(date_str, utc=True)

print(pd_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
>>> '2017-11-21 22:00'
```

And naively if I try to do the same process as with the `datetime` module,
the results are still off:

```
pd_date = pd.to_datetime(date_str, utc=True)
pd_date = pd_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))

print(pd_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
>>> '2017-11-21 23:00'
```

Is there something I am not understanding? Am I using `pd.to_datetime` or something else wrong? On Python 3.6, Windows 7.

Comment: doesn't `'2017-11-21T23:00+0100'` specify timezone `+0100` (Europe/Berlin) instead of UTC? This is `22:00` in UTC

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the string is either labelled wrong or the utc format is given wrong?  What form is it in then? It's in the data that I have, so I need to know how to handle it.

Comment: your use of `replace` to calculate the localtime is wrong. You can just do `astimezone(...)`

Comment: So like `pd_date = pd.to_datetime(date_str, utc=True).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome'))`?

Comment: indeed. You can do that for a whole `Series` with [`tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html#pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert)  `pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(utc_str, utc=True)]).dt.tz_convert(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, I think your code for `local_time` is wrong

```
utc_time
```

> ```
> datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 21, 23, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600))
> ```

```
utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

> ```
> 'datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 21, 23, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)'
> ```

so this `replace` removes the `'+0100` from the `datetime`, but keeps the rest the same

```
utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

> ```
> "datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+1:00:00 STD>)"
> ```

This then adds 1 hour to 23:00UTC, so become the next day midnight in Berlin as expected

```
pd.to_datetime(utc_str, utc=True)
```

> ```
> Timestamp('2017-11-21 22:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
> ```

The difference in behaviour is due to the constructor. `pd.to_datetime` calculates the time and timezone back to 22:00UTC instead of 23:00+0100, so if there you replace the timezone info with UTC, it changes nothing

## Local time

Your `utc_time` object is in the correct timezone, so if you want the local time you can just do `utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` in pandas you'll have to do `pd.to_datetime(utc_str, utc=True).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`

Comment: I see.  It seems that the `utc_time` is in two different forms: the actual UTC `2017-11-21 23:00` and then local offset `+0100`, which when added together, you obtain the local time desired `2017-11-22 00:00`.  I guess this string should probably just remove the offset and then add it as a timedelta, because `utc_time` seems to be in a non-sensical form.

Comment: I mean `utc_str` instead of `utc_time`

Comment: the `utc_string` is not a string of a UTC-time, but a local time representation.

Comment: So is there anyway to make the output `2017-11-22 00:00` from the so-called "`utc_str`"? Using `pd.to_datetime(utc_str, utc=True).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` gives `2017-11-21 23:00`